# how to sum this alternating series with index running from negative to positive infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

In all the examples of alternating series I can find, they always expand from $0$ or $1$ to $\infty$. This one extends from $-\infty$, and cannot simply be said to be ‘even’ in *n*:

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n-1}\left(a\left(n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)-X\right)}{\left(a\left(n+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)-X\right)^2+Z^2}$$

*Mathematica* yields the exact sum as:

$$-\frac{\pi}{2a}\left[\sec\left(\pi\cdot\dfrac{X-iZ}{a}\right)+\sec\left(\pi\cdot\dfrac{X+iZ}{a}\right)\right]$$

Comment: **Hint:** Differentiate the natural logarithm of [Euler's infinite product expression for the sine function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basel_problem).

Comment: @Lucian what do you mean by "infinite product expression"? Just the Taylor series expansion of sine? EDIT: oh, are you referring to the sinx/x expression in the Wiki?

Comment: Actually, you will have to use a similar approach to write $\cos\pi x$ as an infinite product, and then differentiate its natural logarithm.